# Цикл while продолжает работать после выполнения условия

Tags: python

```
l = ['red','green','black']
ctr=0
while ctr <= (len(l)-1):
    l.insert(ctr,'c')
    ctr +=2
print(l)
```

`>>> 'c', 'red', 'c', 'green', 'c', 'black']`

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему цикл while продолжает работать после 2 итерации, хотя на третьей итерации ctr = 4 и больше чем (len(l) - 1) = 2 и вроде бы цикл должен завершиться.
Спасибо!

---

всем спасибо! что длинна списка увеличивается, не догадался :)

Comment: А `l.insert` что делает?

Comment: Размер списка увеличивается на единицу каждую итерацию.

Comment: ``print(l, ctr, len(l))`` в последней строке цикла очень поможет. Ну и https://habr.com/ru/post/339038/ не помешает почитать, особенно абзац начинающися со слова "Наконец, если в вашей программе всё ещё есть баг"

Answer (score 2):

Цикл работает корректно. Происходит 3 итерации.

```
> Первая ctr = 0, длинна списка = 2 (потому что у вас длинна списка - 1)
> вторая ctr = 2, длинна списка = 3 (потому что у вас длинна списка - 1)
> третья ctr = 4, длинна списка = 4 (потому что у вас длинна списка - 1)
```

По этой причине у Вас список с требя "с"